# "Open with" - C# program shows just icon in Windows "Open With" context menu

Tags: c#, .net, explorer, visual-studio-2003, open-with

I have a program, MyApp, where I can open a text file, which works great.
The application is created in C# with Visual Studio 2003, .NET 1.1.

But under the [right-click on file context-menu in Explorer -> "Open With"] just the icon is shown, not the application name or description.

As shown here:
[Open With context-menu (http://data.fuskbugg.se/skalman02/4e450ba043602_openwith.png)](http://data.fuskbugg.se/skalman02/4e450ba043602_openwith.png)

If we look at Notepad++ in the image that text seems to be the description text, same as under File properties general tab for notepad++.exe.

What value is used there? How do I set that value?

[EDIT]:
The registry entries automatically generated when using "open With -> browse for application" are:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\MyApp.exe\shell\open\command
(default) under the key command is: "correct path" "%1"

Comment: Impossible to reverse-engineer the registry content from a screen shot.  Just document what you put in the registry.

Comment: I haven't added anything manually in the registry. But when I do a open with -> browse for application some values are automatially generated under .filextention and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\MyApp

Comment: Have you checked attributes in AssemblyInfo to ensure you have an AssemblyTitle?  Not sure if that's what gets used, but it might be.

Comment: I don't have an answer but this is documented in MSDN at [File Types and File Associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link Kragen :)

@Tuskan360, It really was the AssemblyInfo! I cleared the registry of all entries related to MyApp, and now it got updated... The problem was probably that I tried before without the AssemblyInfo filled out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the AssemblyTitle in AssemblyInfo.cs.  After doing this you may need to remove all the registry entries and re-install your aplication.

*(so other people with the same problem don't need to search through the comment thread)*